# Sending smtp email via gmail

Tags: gnus, smtpmail

I am trying to send email via SMTP in gnus. I can receive email via IMAP just fine, but whenever I try to compose a message send, I get this error:

> smtpmail-send-it: Sending failed: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS
>   command first. e5sm37529pdc.94 - gsmtp

This is my smtpmail-send-it configuration:

```
(setq message-send-mail-function 'smtpmail-send-it
      smtpmail-starttls-credentials '(("smtp.gmail.com" 587 nil nil))
      smtpmail-auth-credentials '(("smtp.gmail.com" 587 "email@example.com" nil))
      smtpmail-default-smtp-server "smtp.gmail.com"
      smtpmail-smtp-server "smtp.gmail.com"
      smtpmail-smtp-service 587
      starttls-use-gnutls t)
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution! I had to tell it where to find gnutls.

```
(setq message-send-mail-function 'smtpmail-send-it
      smtpmail-starttls-credentials '(("smtp.gmail.com" 587 nil nil))
      smtpmail-auth-credentials '(("smtp.gmail.com" 587 "email@example.com" nil))
      smtpmail-default-smtp-server "smtp.gmail.com"
      smtpmail-smtp-server "smtp.gmail.com"
      smtpmail-smtp-service 587
      starttls-gnutls-program "/usr/local/bin/gnutls-cli"
      starttls-extra-arguments nil
      starttls-use-gnutls t)
```